# Is it possible to assign tasks to another user? (different of the logged in)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tasks-api

It would be very useful to manage projects.
All the API I found is to work with tasks for the user logged, but at any company there are managers, coordinators, to assign task, but I don't know if the API allowed it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: While you could use a service account to impersonate other users add tasks to them, I don't think Google Tasks is designed for that. Otherwise the resources would have and `assignee` field or similar. If you are an administrator and think using a service account would be a useful workaround, though, I would consider posting an answer with this.